# Firebase query returns "PERMISSION_DENIED" but rules work in test console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following Firebase rule:

```
match /PendingInvites/{inviteID} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null && 
        isInviteForUser(database, inviteID);
}
```

and the following functions:

```
  function isInviteForUser(database, inviteID) {
  
    let dataItem = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/PendingInvites/$(inviteID)).data;
  
    return (dataItem.userPhone == request.auth.token.phone_number) ||
                    (dataItem.userEmail == request.auth.token.email);
  }
```

The testing against the collection using the online role test works, I've verifies using real documents and with both userPhone and userEmail values (both matching and non-matching).  All work as expected, denying mismatch values and allowing matched values.

This is where is gets strange.  When I run this (Android) query:

```
val companyMemberDocuments = Firebase.firestore.collection("PendingInvites").whereEqualTo("userPhone", firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.phoneNumber).whereEqualTo("userEmail", firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.email).get().await()
```

I get "PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions".  As near as I understand rules, I think it should work.  It works in the online console, I'm specifically querying for userPhone (or userEmail) but it doesn't work.

I've tried removing the userEmail and only testing for userPhone, but that also appears to not work.

Any ideas how I can correct the rules (or query)?

Thanks

Document:

Auth token used in testing:

```
{
  "uid": "",
  "token": {
    "sub": "",
    "aud": "certifly-global",
    "phone_number": "+16505551234",
    "firebase": {
      "sign_in_provider": "phone"
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Document]

**Note how the document includes BOTH, userPhone and userEmail**

Comment: Please show the data in Firestore + the token details for the user you are testing this with

Comment: Added above, the above works in the test console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are rejecting the query every time because [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Be sure to read that documentation and [this post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

Your query is asking for **all** documents in PendingInvites where `userPhone == +16505551234`.  However, your rules do not allow this for two reasons:

1. Your query doesn't match the constraints of rule (that both userPhone and userEmail are set to specific values). The query is just specifying userPhone.
2. The system will not perform a `get()` for every single document that could match.  While this will work for individual document gets from the client, it will not work for queries that could return any number of documents.

So you will have to resolve both problems.

1. Your query will need to filter using both userPhone and userEmail, as required by your rules.  This means you will have to add another `whereEqualTo` on userEmail that matches the requirement of the rules. In other words, the client app needs to pass the user's email in that filter.
2. You don't need to use a `get()` at all in the rules.  You can refer to fields in documents in the current collection via `resource.data`.

The rules will need too something more like this:

```
match /PendingInvites/{inviteID} {
    allow read: if
        request.auth != null && 
        resource.data.userPhone == request.auth.token.phone_number &&
        resource.data.userEmail == request.auth.token.email;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, you are correct in that the query was wrong and needed both values (I had fixed that but pasted the wrong one (edited)).  The rule you suggested is good except it has the same issue I'm trying to resolve.

My issue is that the invitation can have email OR phone OR both (it's intention is to match what the user token contains).  The query works if I include one value or the other but supplying both fails because the document has both but the token has one.

Does this make sense?

Comment: If you need email OR phone, then use a logical or operator, not a logical and.

Comment: That appears to work, as long as I use 2 queries as before (one for phone and one for email).  It looks like the magic is in the rule you suggested.

My original rules used a get() (also ORed) but that must have been incorrect.  Can you explain why (just for my curiosity and future knowledge)?

Comment: I believe I explained why get() doesn't work in my answer.

Comment: So basically, resources.data is the document record in the result set? ,correct?

So get() would be used when you need to reference a document that isn't the same as the document (rule) path; correct?

Comment: Yes, that's when you use get(). https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted but forgot to accept the answer; now accepted, thanks!